# Cannot called a variable from another class in Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm doing a function that will delete a record in a real time Firebase. A person can only delete their own record by knowing the unique ID generated by the `.getKey()`. However when i want implement the `RecordID` to delete, I couldn't called the `RecordID`. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here ? Thanks.

**Error**
[My error demo, the variable doesnt recognize in my delete function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upq6P.png)

**My get class**

```
package com.example.sossystem;

public class SosRecords {
    String RecordID;
    String FullName;
    String PhoneNumber;
    String EmailAddress;


    public SosRecords(){

    }


    public SosRecords(String recordID, String fullName, String phoneNumber, String emailAddress) {
        RecordID = recordID;
        FullName = fullName;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getRecordID() {
        return RecordID;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return FullName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return PhoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return EmailAddress;
    }
}
```

**Error**

The error is showed on the `Stop button`

```
 btnStopSOS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onStop();
                stopLocationUpdates();
                deleteRecords(RecordID);
                result.setText("Dashboard");
                btnStartSOS.setEnabled(true);
                btnStopSOS.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });


    }

    private void deleteRecords(String fullName) {
        DatabaseReference delRecord = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Records").child(RecordID);
        delRecord.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The SOS Request is Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

**My Code**

```
        btnStartSOS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onStart();

                //GET ALL INFORMATION FROM FIRESTORE AND SEND TO REALTIME DATABASE
                if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!= null){
                    DocumentReference df = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    df.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                            if(documentSnapshot.getString("FullName")!= null){

                                String id = reff.push().getKey();
                                Log.d(TAG, "asdasd"+id);
                                SosRecords sosRecords = new SosRecords(id,documentSnapshot.getString("FullName"), (documentSnapshot.getString("PhoneNumber")), (documentSnapshot.getString("UserEmail")  ));
                                reff.child(id).setValue(sosRecords);
                                btnStopSOS.setEnabled(true);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You're are now activating SOS request !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }
                            
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                }

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    checkSettingsAndStartLocationUpdates();
                }else{
                    askLocationPermission();
                }
                }
        });

        btnStopSOS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onStop();
                stopLocationUpdates();
                deleteRecords(RecordID);
                result.setText("Dashboard");
                btnStartSOS.setEnabled(true);
                btnStopSOS.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });


    }

    private void deleteRecords(String fullName) {
        DatabaseReference delRecord = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Records").child(RecordID);
        delRecord.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The SOS Request is Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: just call `getRecordID` or class name then call `getRecordID`

Comment: @Ramesh you mean `sosrecords.getRecordID` ?

Comment: `SosRecords records = new SosRecords();` 
`records.getRecordID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SosRecords sosrecords = new SosRecords();

    btnStopSOS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onStop();
                    stopLocationUpdates();
                    deleteRecords(sosrecords.getRecordID);
                    result.setText("Dashboard");
                    btnStartSOS.setEnabled(true);
                    btnStopSOS.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
    
    
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, i have tried with method but the app crash

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()` Maybe it mean i still dont get the ID ?

Comment: Thanks i did some adjustment and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I successfully solved it by set the value of the Id to my `RecordID`

```
 sosrecords.setRecordID(id);
```